# CsvHelper ошибка при экспорте "Element does not exists" csv файла

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, export, csv-helper

Пытаюсь выгрузить (сделать экспорт) файл с данными о пользователях. Пользователей пока получаем в контроллере из репозитория (1064 элемента), затем отправляем их в экспорт сервис. После чего возникает ошибка `Element does not exists` Может быть кто-нибудь подскажет почему так происходит? Должен ли создаваться файл, если мне нужно всего лишь его сгрузить? В проекте используется ASP.NET Core и библиотека CsvHelper.

```
//UserController.cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Export()
{
    try
    {
        var applicationUsers = await _applicationUserService.GetAllAsync();
        var users = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserExport>>(applicationUsers);
        return await _exportUserService.ExportUsers(users);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}
//ExportUserService.cs
public class ExportUserService : IExportUserService
{
    public async Task<FileResult> ExportUsers(IEnumerable<UserExport> users)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await WriteCsvToMemory(users);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(result);
            return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "text/csv") { FileDownloadName = "export_users.csv" };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task<byte[]> WriteCsvToMemory(IEnumerable<UserExport> users)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            await csvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync<UserExport>(users);
            await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S. Т.е. по сути после выполнение кода ожидается начало скачивания файла, которого, к сожалению, не происходит.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По порядку:

- вы сбрасываете буфер у `streamWriter`, а у `csvWriter`? Почему бы не использовать иерархию из `using`, чтобы всё лишнее зафлашилось и задиспозилось само?
- пишете данные в поток, потом поток преобразуете в массив байт, потом снова в поток. Ладно, чёрт с ней с оперативой, её может быть у вас много, но процессор то не резиновый и перегонять данные туда-сюда без видимой на то причины зачем?
- вы возвращаете файловый поток, когда у вас есть массив байт, почему бы не вернуть сразу массив, тем более что вы уже всё затащили в оперативку, а потом после отправки диспозить `MemoryStream` некому, да прибудет с нами Garbage Collector, заботливо финализирующий всё что мы недодиспозили.

```cs
public class ExportUserService : IExportUserService
{
    public async Task<FileResult> ExportUsers(IEnumerable<UserExport> users)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] content = await WriteCsvToMemory(users);
            return new FileContentResult(content, "text/csv") { FileDownloadName = "export_users.csv" };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private async Task<byte[]> WriteCsvToMemory(IEnumerable<UserExport> users)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                await csvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync<UserExport>(users);
            }
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

> Может быть кто-нибудь подскажет почему так происходит?

Потому что вы не сбросили буфер `csvWriter` в целевой поток.

> Должен ли создаваться файл, если мне нужно всего лишь его сгрузить?

Нет.

*P. S. Лучше вообще использовать JSON.*

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! На счет второго пункта, да, тоже заметил, - вчера уже поправил это) Сейчас добавил ваш код в свой ExportUserService, но, к сожалению, проявляется та же самая ошибка =\

Comment: @Yuriy в таком случае надо понять, где именно она появляется. Поставьте точку останова, посмотрите содержимое байтового ассива, правильно ли сформировался файл. Запишите эти байты на диск для проверки. Не понятно, что такое `Element does not exists`, либо текст ошибки не точный, либо я просто плохо гуглил. Изначально я подумал на проблему отсутствия данных, а теперь не знаю, на что подумать. Доходит ли выполнение кода до формирования CSV?

Comment: @Yuriy Кстати про `return BadRequest(e.Message)`, ошибку 400 следует возвращать, когда пришел непонятный запрос от клиента, а не когда что-то упало при формировании ответа. В вашем случае, так как исключение общего типа, надо возвращать 500.

Comment: да тут react-admin он не хочет выводить BadRequest) прям уже не знаю на что думать, маппинг проходит, байты есть, файл вроде создается - байты в нем есть, но все равно та же самая ошибка

Comment: @Yuriy то есть неизвестно, что именно вызвало ошибку? А что если убрать (закомментировать) все `try-catch`? Оно должно начать где-то падать в конкретном месте.

Comment: к сожалению, без try-catch все то же самое, возможно в этом как то замешан сам react-admin

Comment: @Yuriy что если вы не будете вызывать `WriteCsvToMemory`, а вернете просто `new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test"), "text/csv") {...};`?

Comment: да, та же самая ошибка, похоже, что и впрямь react-admin)
спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @Yuriy тогда я сделал все что мог. :)